# Can I use a template function as another template's parameter?

Tags: c++

For example I have a template function:

```
template <typename T>
void SizeOf() {
  std::cout << sizeof(T) << std::endl;
}
```

and another template function:

```
template <typename T, template<typename S> class F> 
void CallOn(T t) {
  ...
  F<T>();
  ...
}
```

now I want write code like this:

```
double pi = 3.14;
CallOn<double, SizeOf>(pi);
```

Is there anyway I can do this? If so, how to write the code?

P.S. The error message is:

```
/home/liu/source/cppsh/main.cpp:14:3: error: no matching function for call to 'CallOn'
  CallOn<double, SizeOf>(pi);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/liu/source/cppsh/main.cpp:8:6: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'F'
void CallOn(T t) {
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: btw correct syntax would be `template<typename> class F`, thats the second part of the error, and answer also has it correct

Comment: @idclev463035818: not sure it is a typo though, OP might expect `template<typename> function F` (which is not supported).

Comment: Honestly I didn't add the `class` on purpose, since that means to pass a class, not a function. But I decide to add it in my question to avoid talking about the syntax/grammer issue.

Comment: maybe misunderstanding. My comment and the error "invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'F'" is refering to `S` which is wrong (for passing a type template template parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass function template as argument (of function or of template).

You can pass template class as template template argument though:

```
template <typename T>
struct SizeOf
{
  void operator()() const {
    std::cout << sizeof(T) << std::endl;
  }
};

template <typename T, template <typename> class F> 
void CallOn(T t) {
  // ...
  F<T>{}();
  // ...
}
```

Another way would be to pass non-template functor with template method.
In your case (no deduction from arguments as no arguments), it is less convenient (syntax would be `f.operator()<T>();`).

Comment: Hi, I got a further question, what if I want to pass a function with parameters? Can this solution still handle this?

Comment: @ravenisadesk `operator()` can take any parameters you want

Comment: @idclev463035818, thanks, I haven't use `operator()` before, thanks for pointing out.